# Updating Entity Framework model from database error

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, entity-framework, model

I have the PostgreSQL database on remote server. And when i'm trying to update entity model in my web-project from database in visual studio i get such error:

> Unable to convert connection string for execution time to its
>   equivalent for development time.

There is my connectionstring:

```
metadata=res://*/Model.MerModel.csdl|res://*/Model.MerModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.MerModel.msl;provider=Npgsql;provider connection string=&quot;PORT=5432;TIMEOUT=15;POOLING=True;MINPOOLSIZE=1;MAXPOOLSIZE=20;COMMANDTIMEOUT=20;COMPATIBLE=2.2.5.0;DATABASE=****;HOST=***.***.*.**;PASSWORD=********;USER ID=postgres&quot;"
```

Connection parameters are correct. Using them I can connect to a database in PostgreSQL Client. Help me, please. What is the problem?

**UPD:** Finally i found solution for my problem. I deleted Npgsql and Npgsql.EntityFramework packages from the project (to make clean installation of new versions). Then i installed Npgsql v.3.2.7 and EntityFramework6.Npgsql v.3.1.1. After this i deleted "COMPATIBLE=2.2.5.0" from my connectionstring. Then it was necessary to rebuild all the project. Note that Npgsql PostgreSQL Integration VSIX must be installed in your Visual Studio. Finally i can update my EF model from the database and check if it is correct after this manipulations.

Comment: Seems that its a bug in the provider, I suggest to find their community and ask there. Anyway try to update model from database hosted on your machine not remote and let us know the feedback.

Comment: @MohammadAlghanem I have just tried to update model from local database hosted on my machine. And I got the same error. 
I'm going to write them on github about this issue.

Comment: Go ahead , please update this post if you found a solution.

Comment: @MohammadAlghanem, I found the solution.